# Unable to resolve jquery noconflict for multiple versions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here are the details which i am using in page...

```
<!--------slider script------------->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<!---------------------anchor tag smooth scroller on same page--> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!----smooth scrooler up--->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When i am going to use all three script parallel then slider script is not working so give me solution how can i use all together.

Comment: Including **3** versions of jQuery in a page (including an *extremely* old version) is a recipe for disaster. Find widgets that are actively supported with an up-to-date version of the library and use just one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: 'can you recommend me latest version or download link ? @Pointy'

Comment: @Er.SanjeevSoni have you visited [jquery.com](http://jquery.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

Using `jQuery.noConflict()` function you can put multiple jquery on same page.
For example,

```
<!--------slider script------------->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
var j1 = jQuery.noConflict();

<!---------------------anchor tag smooth scroller on same page-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
var j2 = jQuery.noConflict();

<!----smooth scrooler up--->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
var j3 = jQuery.noConflict();

j1(document).ready(function($) { /* write script here */ }
j2(document).ready(function($) { /* write script here */ }
j3(document).ready(function($) { /* write script here */ }
```

Hope this will help you.